# How do I get it to loop while getting it to save what happened within the loop?

Tags: python, loops

```
import random
mnstrhp=100
playerhp=100
mnstrtyperndm=random.randint(1,3)
mnstrtype=None
if mnstrtyperndm==1:
    mnstrtype='Orc'
    print("You've encountered an orc in the wild!")
if mnstrtyperndm==2:
    mnstrtype='Giant'
    print("You've encountered a giant in the wild!")
if mnstrtyperndm==3:
    mnstrtype='Dragon'
    mnstrhp=150
    print("You've encountered a dragon in the wild, this one is stronger than most normal monsters, be careful!")
swordname=input("What would you like to name your sword? ")
while mnstrhp>0:
    randatk=random.randint(1,10)  
    randheal=random.randint(1,10)
    mnstratkchance=random.randint(1,2)
    mnstratk=random.randint(1,10)
    atkorheal=input("Would you like to attack the " + mnstrtype + " or heal yourself? ")
    if 'attack' in atkorheal:
        print("You did" , randatk , "damage to the " + mnstrtype + " with " , swordname , "!")
        print("The " + mnstrtype + "'s current health is " , mnstrhp-randatk)
    if 'heal' in atkorheal:
        print("You healed for" , randheal  , "health!")
        print("Your current hp is " , playerhp+randheal)
    if mnstratkchance==1:
        print("The " + mnstrtype + " hit you for " , mnstratk , " damage, it brought your health down to " , playerhp-mnstratk , "!")
    if mnstratkchance==2:
        print("the " + mnstrtype + " attempted to hit you, but it failed.")
```

I am trying to get it to save what damage the player did, but every time it loops, the health resets back to 100, is there any way to fix this? All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the health variable. You can do it with the `-=` operator. `x -= 1` is equivalent to `x = x - 1`.

```py
while mnstrhp>0:
    # etc
    if 'attack' in atkorheal:
        mnstrhp -= randatk # add this line
        print("You did...")
        # etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is definitely that you never assign calculated value to the variable. When your print something like `mnstrhp-randatk` it doesn't change `mnstrhp` variable value. To really change it you should assign the value doing `mstrhp = mstrhp-randatk`.